# Python - Output Elements in Two Lists on Separate Lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to figure out how I would print each element in both lists on seperate lines like:

Chapter One Test   [large space]                84%

but instead, it prints the whole list out like:

['Chapter One Test', 'Chapter Two Test', 'Chapter Three Test']        [84%,
75%, 90%]

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
>>> li1=['Chapter One Test', 'Chapter Two Test', 'Chapter Three Test']
>>> li2=['84%', '75%', '90%']
```

You can [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#zip) the two lists together:

```
>>> print('\n'.join(['{}\t{}'.format(*t) for t in zip(li1,li2)]))
Chapter One Test    84%
Chapter Two Test    75%
Chapter Three Test  90%
```

If you want to make a table, you might make the field widths fixed rather than `\t` separated:

```
>>> print('\n'.join(['{:22s}{:3s}'.format(*t) for t in zip(li1,li2)]))
Chapter One Test      84%
Chapter Two Test      75%
Chapter Three Test    90%
```

Read more about format [mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) to find out more about those options.

Comment: This is the more pythonic answer in my opinion. Thanks dawg

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3? If Python 3, add the parenthesis for `print`

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
   for test, grade in zip(testSet, calculatedMarks):
       print("{}    {}".format(test, grade))
```

Your example would print the *entire* lists in a single `print` call.

This will iterate over the lists (creating pairs from each list using `zip`) and print each pair on it's own line.

As in Dawg's answer, you can use a list comprehension and the `str.join` function instead of a for loop with a body to get this in a single line/print statement.

Answer (score 0):

Sticking with your current approach you could make small adjustments by either printing the `index`'s one by one or making a loop using the `index` from one of the `enumerated` lists since they have equal length and sorted to match already, I would also say look into `l.just` and `r.just` to achieve formatting that lines up nicely

```
print ("{}                     {}".format(testSet[0], calculatedMarks[0]))
print ("{}                     {}".format(testSet[1], calculatedMarks[1]))
print ("{}                     {}".format(testSet[2], calculatedMarks[2]))

for idx, item in enumerate(testSet):
    print("{}                      {}".format(testSet[idx], calculatedMarks[idx]))
```

Comment: If you assume the two lists have the same number of indices, why use `enumerate` instead of `zip`?

Comment: I'm also assuming that if OP could not piece this together that a more gradual step in the right direction would be something he would grasp and not too foreign, loops with `enumerate` is a smaller step then `zip`